# Does daily crossfit excercise and a paleo diet reduce heart disease?

Tags: diet, paleo-diet, crossfit

Does doing daily crossfit excercises and eating a paleo diet consisting of lean meat, vegetables, etc. reduce heart disease?

Comment: Non fitness relation nutrition questions are off-topic. Also, there have been no long term studies for the paleo diet. Some short term studies show favorable improvements in lipid profiles: http://yaboga.com/paleo-metabolic.pdf

Comment: agreed on both counts.

Comment: what stackexchange server would be good for this question?

Comment: Unfortunately, none at the moment. Just rephrase the question to ask about crossfit with paleo (crossfit is fond of the paleo diet) and you're on topic.

Comment: @EhevuTov Robin was making a joke. It's still not on topic. No one knows the answer to your question.

Comment: No, I wasn't, There's really nowhere else to put it, and it is on topic now, by the standards of other questions that are allowed to remain.

Comment: I think this is too broad. It's not nutrition that makes me think this should be closed--it's the fact that it requires lengthy advanced chemistry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no and maybe.

Unfortunately, that's going to be about the best answer you will get. Exercise has proven to be a heart disease limiter, and certainly reduces the risk factor of obesity (Assuming you don't eat massive amounts and stay fat), so in that sense, yes, it can reduce heart disease. But, if you still smoke and/or eat a bad diet, it's not going to be a cure-all.

As far as the paleo diet, it's another "fad" diet in my opinion. It's an attempt by people to find a short cut to maintaining a healthy weight. Eat a balanced amount of the macronutrients (carbs, protein, fats), with an emphasis on healthy fats (avocado, nuts, fish oils, healthy cooking oils, etc) and a variety of fruits/veggies, and you should be fine.

Note, you will need to tweak your diet slightly (or possibly majorly) if you have sensitivities such as gluten, lactose intolerance, or other digestive problems, or if you need more of a macronutrient for athletic purposes (Endurance athletes need a higher percentage of carbs than a powerlifter for example).